# How to set width and height to qr scanner in ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, qr-code

I am using  qr scanner in my ionic2 application.I am uisng this link
 **https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/qr-scanner/.**

All are working fine, but camera shows entire screen.
I want to show certain width and height of qrscanner. 
please help me....